# On AWS Lambda, how can I replace the standard libstdc++.so.6

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

On the standard AWS Lambda distribution

```
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
```

symlinks to

`libstdc++.so.6.0.19`

I am running software that needs a newer version, `libstdc++.so.6.0.24`

First, I tried changing the symlink, but the default user doesn't have sufficient privileges.

Then I tried to run as `sudo` but apparently this is not allowed with a lambda function.

How can I replace the default symlink to use a newer library?

Comment: which programming language are you using in your Lambda function ?

Comment: You can find some guidance [here](https://bezdelev.com/hacking/aws-lambda-libstdc-glibcxx_3420-not-found/)

Answer (score 1):

I would try to add the specific version of the library you need into a Lambda Layer (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html)

These are unzipped to `/opt` at runtime and added to `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` so it will be picked up by the loader before the native one.

Be sure to include a binary compiled for Amazon Linux as this is the underlying distribution used by AWS Lambda.

As Thales explained in another answer, you will break the 'serverless' concept by doing so.  You will be responsible to maintain that part of the operating system, like provide update when new versions will be published etc.

Comment: Great answer, Sebastien. I didn't mention layers because the OP mentioned he wanted to change where the symlink was pointing to, but I should've been more proactive (just like you). Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: Thank you - I never tried this with .so files. I would be interested to hear back from Hoa to check if this works as expected.